# How can I remove freckles from my skin?

Tags: personal-care

my question is that: how to remove freckles from my face? As my face  is completely covered by freckles and it becomes more prominant when I apply makeup or any other cosmetic to my skin. It becomes very embarrassing for me when I go to any event. According to my point of view, freckles, wrinkles or pimples appear on the skin because of some deficiency or lack of something in our body. So what's the reason behind the appearance of freckles on the skin?

Comment: freckles are rusty nerve endings, so you've got nerves of steel ;)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a health issue. Please see the [tour].

Answer (score 2):

Freckles are generally harmless. A freckle is usually caused by exposure to ultraviolet light which darkens the pigment in the skin and as a result are more common in the summertime and fade in the winter. Genetics play a role as well in the formation of freckles. Use sunscreen when outside in the sun and don't overdo the sunshine exposure and it should rectify itself.

Answer (score 0):

For removing freckles take one lemon juice and dip a cotton ball then apply it on your face in the freckled area ,after ten minutes when you see soaking the juice in your skin wash it with cold water,apply this process twice a week.